# angular 10 checkbox value becomes undefined

Tags: angular

I configured the following formGroup in my component :

```
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      product: new FormControl(),
      shops: new FormGroup({})
    });
  }
```

When I choose a vendor from a select bar, I want to load all its shops as checkboxes.
In the function that loads the checkboxes I fill the formgroup :

```
  loadShops(product: string): void {
    this.apiService.getShopsThatSellProduct(product).subscribe({
      next: data => {
        this.shops = data;
        const checkboxes: FormGroup =  this.form.get('shops') as FormGroup;
        checkboxes.reset();
        this.shops.forEach((shop, index) => {
          checkboxes.addControl('shop_' + index, new FormControl(shop));
        });
      }
      ,
      error: err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

In my html I used the following code :

```
  <div class="shops">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Shops"  >
        <mat-option formGroupName="shops" *ngFor="let someFormControl of form.get('shops').value | keyvalue">
          <mat-checkbox  [formControlName]="someFormControl.key"> {{someFormControl.value.name}}</mat-checkbox>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

Every shop has the following fields :

```
{
name: string
owner: string
address : string
}
```

After choosing a product the shops list is updated. However, all the shops are selected by default and when I try to select/unselect any shop option the value becomes undefinied.

Why `{{someFormControl.value.name}}` becomes undefinied after the first "unselect" for every option ?

[stackbiz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jqucog?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missunderstood what a form control value is. you used this code to create a form control:

```
checkboxes.addControl('shop_' + index, new FormControl(shop));
```

This will create a FormControl with initial value of `shop`, which is an object like:

```
{
  name: 'Dan',
  age: 30
}
```

So at first, your shop is selected because this object is truthy. and after you unselect it, it will change to: `false`, so `someFormControl.value.name` will get undefined ( because `false.name` is undefined), so your label will get disappeared.

To fix it, you can change `new FormControl(shop)` to `new FormControl(false)` to make it unselected at start and change `someFormControl.value.name` to `someFormControl.index` to show the name of person as label. (or `data['USA'][i].age` to display age as lable.)

[See It On stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-12piod?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @JeyJ there was couple of other issues in your stackblitz, fixed them also. (1. you forgot to write `[formGroup]="form"` to bind your form to formGroup . 2. you should change `someFormControl.age` to `someFormControl.value.age`)

Comment: So form controller is actually a tool that helps me mapping multiple objects (or single one) by their index to a boolean/string value ? I thought it can return me the object that was selected after I press submit but I understand that I was wrong.

Comment: @JeyJ yes. form control is for displaying the form data. it has a key, and a value. in your example you're using the name of the shop for key, and the value of the form control is the the checkbox value (true / false). since you have the index of form control (the name of shop), you can give the object from the actual data by using that index. so there is no need to store an extra object in form control. (you can see in stackblitz demo that the age is shown also.). anyway if you want to store objects in form control, you can search : `angular form control store object`. there is some ways.